# 345 vfscanf-internal.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gdb, scanf

my code run on Linux

I do CSAPP lab cachelab, and I use this implementation to extract the variable.

But when I use gdb to debug, I found this error message.

My code looks like this

```
FILE *tracefile = fopen(t, "r");
fscanf(tracefile,"%s %x,%d",opt,&address,&size)
```

The file t looks like this:

```
 S 00602264,1
 L 00602260,4
 L 0060225c,4
 L 00602400,8
 S 7fefe05a8,8
 S 7fefe05a0,8
 S 7fefe058c,4
 S 7fefe0588,4
 S 7fefe0580,8
 S 7fefe0578,8
 L 7fefe058c,4
 S 7fefe0570,4
 L 7fefe0588,4
 S 7fefe0574,4
 S 7fefe0590,4
 L 7fefe0590,4
```

The error message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__vfscanf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x555555557020 "%s %x,%d", argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffd920, 
    mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=2) at vfscanf-internal.c:345 345     vfscanf-internal.c: No such file or directory.
```

why I do not have the source file for C library function implementation?

Compilation succeeds, but execution fails

One answer is that: The mistake is that you are not checking whether your call to `fopen` succeeds.

The original code is right over here: https://pastebin.com/kb1fXJ2Y

Comment: The parameter list says `s=0x0`. That's the `FILE*` that `fscanf` accepts. The mistake is that you are not checking whether your call to `fopen` succeeds.

Comment: Is your question why you get a `SIGSEGV` or why you do not have the source file for C library function implementation?

Comment: As others have commented, the failure root cause is that `fopen` failed (you should _always_ check error returns). The `vfscanf-internal.c` is _irrelevant_, but see the other answer if you want to understand it.